# Is the JDK standard EC KeyPairGenerator suitable for use with both ECDSA and ECDH algorithms?

Tags: java, key-generation, ecc

I've seen various references on the web for generating Elliptic Curve `KeyPair`s in Java, and the two most commonly referenced examples (unsurprisingly) use the JDK default provider and BouncyCastle.

But what confuses me is that the JDK default provider [supports](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/StandardNames.html#KeyPairGenerator) a single `KeyPairGenerator` algorithm name of `EC` while BouncyCastle also supports that as well as two additional distinct algorithm names of `ECDSA` and `ECDH`:

JDK default provider example:

```
KeyPairGenerator g = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("EC");
ECGenParameterSpec spec = new ECGenParameterSpec("secp256r1");
g.initialize(spec);
KeyPair keyPair = g.generateKeyPair();
```

BouncyCastle provider `ECDSA` example:

```
KeyPairGenerator g = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("ECDSA", "BC");
ECGenParameterSpec spec = new ECGenParameterSpec("secp256r1");
g.initialize(spec);
KeyPair keyPair = g.generateKeyPair();
```

BouncyCastle provider `ECDH` example:

```
KeyPairGenerator g = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("ECDH", "BC");
ECGenParameterSpec spec = new ECGenParameterSpec("secp256r1");
g.initialize(spec);
KeyPair keyPair = g.generateKeyPair();
```

In summary, the BouncyCastle provider supports all three algorithm names, `EC`, `ECDSA` and `ECDH` while the JDK default provider supports only `EC`.

Why the discrepancy?  Is there any meaningful difference in the resulting keys used in any of these approaches?

Comment: Crossdupe but ursinely answered https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4969570/is-there-a-difference-between-ecdh-and-ecdsa-keys

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Oracle Java documentation is a little sparse on the topic, but it does look like with the SunJCE, a key generated as`EC` can be used with either ECDH or ECDSA. ([source](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/security/oracleproviders.htm#GUID-A47B1249-593C-4C38-A0D0-68FA7681E0A7)):

[image: SunEC provider algorithm specs]

(I'm not an Elliptic curve expert, but) Theoretically, I believe that the [domain parameters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_curve_cryptography#Domain_parameters) for ECDH and ECDSA have the same form, that is the equation of the curve and a base point `G`

```
(CURVE, G)
```

(*You'll often see the expanded form*

```
(p, a, b, G, n, h)
```

*where `p, a, b` are the equation of the curve, and `n, h` are values derived from `G`, provided to save computation*)

And the keypairs for both algorithms are the same, namely:

```
priv_key: an integer d in [1, n-1]
pub_key: a point on the curve Q = (x,y) = d*G
```

---

**Bottom line:** Yes, keys are interchangeable between ECDH and ECDSA. Having dug through the Oracle documentation, I'm too lazy to go through Bouncy Castle too, but I would assume that `EC`, `ECDH` and `ECDSA` are all aliases to the same thing, put there to avoid confusion.

Comment: That was my assumption too - but the domain parameters explanation (and link) really helped clarify/settle this for me. Thanks for the answer Mike - it is much appreciated!